# Forcing \alph to latin symbols in a multilingual document

Tags: xetex, numbering, counters, languages

If I use `\alph{..}` inside a hebrew block in a XeLaTeX document, I get a Hebrew numeral instead of a latin numeral. For example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Ezra SIL}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{5}
\alph{section}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

How do I force latin numerals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load the [alphalph](http://ctan.org/pkg/alphalph) package. Then,

```
\alphalph{\value{section}}
```

generates a lowercase-latin "numeral" to represent the value of the counter named `section`.

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Ezra SIL}

\usepackage{alphalph}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{5}
\alphalph{\value{section}}
\end{document}
```