# Forcing latin alphabet as a footnote mark

Tags: formatting, numbering, footnotes

in a multilingual document (greek and english) i want to change the footnote mark from arabic numbers to the latin alphabet. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303186/forcing-alph-to-latin-symbols-in-a-multilingual-document) is how i try to do it,but when i compile it with `xelatex` i get the greek alphabet instead.

here is a mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math,xgreek}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFS Didot}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}    

\usepackage{alphalph}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\alphalph{\value{footnote}}

\begin{document}

some text\footnote{test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `xgreek` explicitly redefines `\@alph` and `\@Alph` to use greek numbers.

If those specific greek numbering style is not needed in the rest of the document, it's possible to switch back to the Latin style by catching the original definition and return to them after `xgreek` has been loaded.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@alph\@alph
\let\latex@Alph\@Alph
\makeatother
\usepackage{unicode-math,xgreek}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial Black}%
%GFS Didot}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}    

%\alphalph{\value{footnote}}

\makeatletter
\let\@alph\latex@alph
\let\@Alph\latex@Alph
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\alph{section}
some text\footnote{test}

\end{document}
```

**Improved version**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math,xgreek}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{alphalph}



\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial Black}%
%GFS Didot}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}    


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{%
  \latin@alph{\c@footnote}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\alph{section}
some text\footnote{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just saw, there's a better way: `\nogreekalph` and `\greekalph`

Comment: so, how can i use `\nogreekalph` command? i tried `\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\nogreekalph{footnote}}` and i got an error

Comment: @Yorgos: No, `\nogreekalph` etc. are switches actually, not counter formaters.

Comment: you a right, `\nogreekalph` command is more convenient :)

Comment: @Yorgos: See the 2nd version, with direct usage of \latin@alph